# Flutter WebView not loading url's that do not contain http:// or https://

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to load the webpage 'artcamp.works'

When I try, it seems that webview is putting the 'http://artcamp.works/ to attempt to load the webpage. Does anyone know a way to do this?

----------------------WebViewWidget------------------------------------------

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WebViewWidget> createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'artcamp.works',      
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    );
  }
}
```

--------------------artcampworks_screen----------------------------

```
class ArtCampWorksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/artcampworks';

  @override
  State<ArtCampWorksScreen> createState() => _ArtCampWorksScreenState();
}

class _ArtCampWorksScreenState extends State<ArtCampWorksScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // companyLogo here would be ice
        title: Text('ArtCamp.Works'),
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: WebViewWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

[output when opening webviewwidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeNDd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I checked WebView docs and examples on pub.dev. I think that it is not possible to load the webpage without http or https. :/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently with wordpress you just need to add the https:// prefix to the address and it will allow the webview widget to load the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).